# Can't get to Jenkins Server from a particular PC

Tags: jenkins

We have a Tomcat application server on buildl02 on our site. This Tomcat instance is running both Jenkins and Sventon.

When I type in the address for Jenkins `http://buildl02.tcprod.local/jenkins`, I get a dialog box that says

> Internet Explorer cannot open the Internet site `http://buill02.tcprod.local/jenkins`.  Operation Aborted.

After that, I get the page, that's says:

> Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage. Most likely causes:
>
> - You are not connected to the Internet.
> - The website is encountering problems.
> - There might be a typing error in the address.

However, I have no problems if I type in the address on the same server for Sventon which is in the same `webapps` directory as Jenkins.

One more thing, Jenkins favicon and webpage title does display (but that's it).

Unfortunately, this is a server, and I cannot download Chrome or Firefox. There's nothing in the Event log.

Comment: Is Fiddler also out of the question?

Comment: Nope. I get the security bar, I tell it to download anyway, and nothing happens. Interestingly I could install Notepad++, but not Firefox or Chrome. This is a Windows 2003 Server, and I couldn't install IE 8 either.

Comment: Did it download and not run, or not download at all?

Comment: It didn't download at all. I clicked on the security bar, asked it to download, but got no dialog box. Nothing.

Comment: Download it somewhere else and copy it over

Comment: I honestly hope that the buildl02 vs buill02 in the 2 addresses you reported is just a typo of yours. Can you confirm?

Comment: Typos. If I could spell, I would have been an English Major.

Comment: ok so let's get down to business. you're not getting a web server error like a 404 or 500 error. 1. Can you ping the server from your client? 2. Can you try to disable windows firewall as a test on the server? 3. What do you mean by "I cannot download Chrome or Firefox"?

Comment: You are running tomcat on port 80?  Show the URL you use to get to Sventon.

Comment: I can get to the other URL `http://buildl02.tcprod.local/svn` which is on the same server and using the same Tomcat instant. Why that works and not `http://buildl02.tcprod.local/jenkins` doesn't is a mystery. IT services says there's no filtering going on. We are beginning to think this is an IE 7 issue. Unfortunately, we can't even upgrade to IE 8 because this is Server 2003. I've asked IT to install Chrome on this box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an IE 8 issue. We installed Google Chrome on the server and we can now get to our Jenkins build server. I've setup a Master/Slave relationship with this PC. Now, it appears that this is a 1.1 .NET project, and I don't have an MSBUILD executable for that on my build machine.